# Yii2 Column in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2

The query that is causing the error is below:

```
 $query = $model::find()
        ->leftJoin('reseller_config', 'reseller_rate.resellerref = reseller_config.resellerref')
        ->select('reseller_rate.*, reseller_config.resellerref AS rate_increase');
```

The sql generated is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reseller_rate` LEFT JOIN `reseller_config` ON reseller_rate.resellerref = rc.resellerref WHERE `resellerref`=56
```

I know it's not working because the fields are named the same and it doesn't know which one to grab.

Does anyone know how I can work around this?

Comment: In the select method you are calling `reseller_rates`, whereas in the join your are calling `reseller_rate` (without s)

Comment: Sorry that's a typo will edit now - in my code it is correct

Comment: where did the `WHERE `resellerref`=56` came from?! it's not in the query!

Comment: That is auto-generated by yii from the ->leftJoin statement

Comment: I think that query is run first to figure out how many records you have in total , used to build the pagination

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $model::find()
    ->leftJoin('reseller_config', 'reseller_rate.resellerref = reseller_config.resellerref')
    ->select('reseller_rate.*', 'reseller_config.resellerref AS rate_increase');
```

you can use this with query bulider :

```
 $model = (new Query())
            ->select(['reseller_rate.*', 'reseller_config.resellerref AS rate_increase')
            ->from('reseller_rate')
            ->leftJoin('reseller_config', 'reseller_rate.resellerref = reseller_config.resellerref')
            ->all();
```